# Iteratively implement Euclid's Algorithm in C

Tags: c, algorithm, iteration

I have 2 types of implementation of Euclid's Algorithm using iteration, not recursion.
One is common:

```
void myXEuclid(int a, int b)
{
    int prevx = 1, x = 0;
    int prevy = 0, y = 1;
    int q, r;

    while (b)
    {
        q = a / b;
        r = a % b;

        int tmp = x;
        x = prevx - q * x;
        prevx = tmp;

        tmp = y;
        y = prevy - q * y;
        prevy = tmp;

        a = b;
        b = r;
    }
    printf("prevx = %d, prevy = %d\n", prevx, prevy);
}
```

I don't really understand where the initializations come from:

```
int prevx = 1, x = 0;
int prevy = 0, y = 1;
```

Anyway, I can still get the right answer from the snippet above. But in RSA algorithm when I do A*B mod n = 1, I have to ensure B is the minimum nonnegative number. So here comes the next confusing implementation of Euclid's Algorithm, also using iteration:

```
int Euc(int A, int B)
{
    int a = A, b = B;
    int quotient, remainder, lastY;
    int x = 0, y = 1;

    int X = 1, Y = 1;

    while (a)
    {
        quotient = b / a;
        remainder = b % a;
        b = a;
        a = remainder;
        lastY = y;
        y *= quotient;

        if (X == Y)
        {
            if (x >= y)
            {
                y = x - y;
            } 
            else
            {
                y = y - x;
                Y = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            y = x + y;
            X = 1 - X;
            Y = 1 - Y;
        }

        x = lastY;
    }

    if (X == 0)
    {
        x = B - x;
    }

    return x;
}
```

I don't know what the capital variable X and Y means and where, again, their initializations come from. But the function above can return x meeting the equation  A * x mod B = 1, and it's the minimum nonnegative one.

I can understand the recursive one. But not the iterative ones. To be honest, I have not slept well for days.

I am not from a English-speaking country. So if you can help me, Please explain simply and in detail. Thanks. Merci.

Comment: This is not the extended version of the euclidean algorithm. The extended version gives you also a linear combination of the gcd(a,b) with a and b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a bit elaborated explanation about GCD algorithm and different implementation in C/C++

http://512algorithms.blogspot.co.il/